# use regex to select words between html tags

Tags: html, regex

thanks for visiting my questions here. I'm trying to match sentences between tags. for example:

> `<h1>` Most flavors, except the ones discussed below, have only one
> metacharacter that matches both before a word and after a word. `<p>`
> This is because any position between characters can never be both at
> the start and at the end of a word. Using only one operator makes
> things easier for you.`<p>`Word boundaries, as described above, are
> supported by most regular expression flavors.

I'm trying to get 10 words from each tag.
output:

- Most flavors, except the ones discussed below, have only one
- This is because any position between characters can never be
- Word boundaries, as described above, are supported by most regular

I find it's so tricky. Thanks for your help here!!!

Comment: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/17447)

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php or [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php) for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been linked in the comment, one of the [most well-known answers of all time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/17447) on this site is about how you using regular expressions to parse HTML is probably not a good idea. For a more detailed and balanced overview of when it is and isn't a good idea to do so, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not) as well.

But briefly, the answer depends on what you're trying to do. It's likely that you'll be better off finding an HTML/XML-parsing library for whatever language you're using, and extracting the text with that.

I'm a bit confused as to what your task actually is, as your code as shown isn't valid HTML, since `<h1>` at least requires a closing tag. But if you do need to use regex to do this, you will want to look at word boundaries and interval operators for limiting to 10, and perhaps lookbehind (or just capture groups) to match the tag without returning it.

But again: if you're trying to parse actual HTML, you'd be better of using an HTML parser to get the tag content, and then getting the first 10 words using string operators. An example in Javascript, which is a bit of a cheat because you get the HTML parsing for free, but it makes for an easy example:

```js
for(const tag of document.querySelectorAll('body *')) {
  console.log(`${tag.tagName}: ${tag.innerText.split(' ').slice(0,5).join(' ')}`)
}
```

```html
<h1>This is an h1 tag with a bunch of text in it that is really long</h1>

<p>Here's a p tag with some more text that's really long
<p>Here's a p tag with some more text that's really long
<p>Here's a p tag with some more text that's really long
<p>Here's a p tag with some more text that's really long
```